# How to stop bots from submitting web forms

Tags: javascript, php, python, mechanize

I'm making a website that requires the user to sign up and log in. My friend keeps making bots with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). The bot signs up for the site multiple times. When the bot makes tonnes of users, the users are added to a database table.

I've made a program to stop an entry that has example in it since the bot just has a variable like:

```
name = 0
```

and keeps adding 1 to the name variable.

I think he has a while loop like this:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
br.set_handle_robots(False) # Ignores the robots.txt file

name = 0
person = 'example',name

while True:
    br.select_form( 'signup' )
    br.form[ 'fullname' ] = person
    br.submit()
    name = name + 1
```

So he basically has this program running non stop until the program crashes.

I want to be able to stop this with either javascript or php.

I've searched for an answer to this but all of the methods that I've tried have failed. I've tried making a timer to see how long the person was on the page since a bot is only on a webpage for about a second. I've made the timer in php and javascript and they both failed.

I've considered captcha but the bot can still send private messages and I don't think the user will stay on the site if they have to fill in a captcha everytime they want to message a friend. And I don't want to have a captcha on the sign up form because it doesn't look to attractive.

I've ran out of ideas to  stop this. It's been going on for a couple ofmonths and it's really slowed downthe development of the site as i have to keep checking for any entries that my program may have missed.

Does anyone know of any other ways to stop a bot.

Comment: Are you trying to protect your site against bots in general, or just against your friend's bot? If the latter, surely there are easier ways....

Comment: My friend seems to have thought of every way around it.

Comment: You'll stop 99% of all bots with a simple hidden input that the bot won't know is hidden and still try to fill out.

Comment: my friend looks at the html via the View Source option on firefox. Would he not see that there is a field in the source that isn't visible on the webpage.

Comment: Your friend probably would, but noone else is going to spend hours creating a bot for your site only.

Comment: Use a captcha, but only on the first page. When the user passes the captcha, set a session variable so they don't need to do it again.

Comment: BTW, it sounds like you need to get better friends. :)

Comment: If there were an easy way, they wouldn't have had to invent captchas.

Comment: What about appending "action" attribute of your form element after DOM loaded?

Comment: See my answer below, but adding to the idea @adeneo proposes, you can make the field name unique on each request (along with a unique value each time).

Comment: How would Facebook or Twitter stop bots since they don't use captcha?

Comment: They don't... Facebook is aware that there's a huge number of fake users on the site.

Comment: Barmar: 'BTW, it sounds like you need to get better friends. :) ' That's exactly what I've been thinking :-D lol

Comment: FB and Twitter are both aware of the huge # of fake accounts. But those fake accounts also allow them to over state how many users they actually have. Thus more eyeballs per day and importance than they really have. I'm sure it didn't hurt either's IPO.

Comment: So they are aware of the fake accounts but they don't do anything about this because it looks like more people use their site?

Comment: Also, I'm not worried about fake accounts being made on my site but I am worried that someone is able to spam my databases using a bot. When that bot makes an account it adds a user to a databse and then adds a chat.xml, friends.xml and profilepic.jpg so after a while my server will be filled with all of these files and I will run out of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have released their new "reCAPTHA" technology, which with a mere check of a box. Bots can get around this, but it's very difficult to do so. By using this, you can reduce the risk of your friend's bot. To the extent of my knowledge, Mechanize does not currently have a way around this.

Comment: Cool, on a scale from 1 to 10 how hard is it to get around this?

Comment: I'd say around an 8. I only know of one program that can get around it, but it takes a lot of effort and it costs a lot of money per year. As someone already said, it's unlikely that anyone but this 'friend' will spend any length of time hacking your website.

Answer (score 1):

Add email confirmation on sign-up, along with a unique email address constraint in your application or persistence layer.

Combine this with adeneo's suggestion of using a hidden field and you'll reduce bot registrations. Note, you can use a unique field name + value each time, making it more difficult to attack.

Note, many of the suggestions given so far are to foil generic attacks. It's a different thing altogether to deal with somebody specifically attacking your site by evaluating its weaknesses.

Comment: My friend has said that there is a way to stop his bot that he doesn't know how to get around. He won't tell me what it is. I'm starting to think that he lied about that. What do you think?

Comment: There are all sorts of approaches you can take, but you generally have to balance the benefits over the impact. For example, more stringent login requirements, such as the IP check suggested below, or number of logins within a period of time may impact some users (if you're a popular site, the IP check may impact students or employees in a large company).

Comment: It also sounds like your friend isn't really much of a friend. Do the smart thing and enforce email confirmation on sign up.

Comment: Email confirmation isn't that hard to circumvent. Email providers like Gmail used (and may still) put numbers and such at the end of your email address and still have arrive in the correct mailbox. The purpose was so that you could use these addresses to create filters in Gmail but still have it all end up in 1 account. I don't think Gmail is alone in this practice. Writing something to eliminate all of the possible ways some providers allow you to present your email address sounds like a nightmare to me.

Comment: There's actually lots of free auto-registering email services out there so if you go the email confirmation route you'll need to maintain a blacklist / whitelist as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to me would seem to be to implement login with a third party such as Facebook and don't offer a standard login form at all.

Alternatively, you could implement a system to store a user's IP address when they create an account, together with a counter, and if more than a certain number of accounts get created from that IP address within a certain time period, then take corrective action, such as suspending those accounts.

I have a feeling it might also be possible to create a custom filter using `fail2ban` that would do the job - that way if a user tried to sign up too many times in a certain period they could be blocked for a given length of time.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure if the users would be ok with me storing their ip address. When I put myself into the shoes of the adverage computer user, they might think that I'm trying to hack them or something like that.

Comment: What on earth makes you think that? On the contrary, IP addresses are very commonly stored in order to maintain sessions. Many MVC frameworks will employ them in their session system, and they get recorded in web server logs.

Comment: Yea no. Sorry roggie. Thats not something you need to worry about. It takes more than an IP to hack.

Comment: True phix, but I was just thinking what would someone with no computer knowledge think about that. Would I have to have a pop up(like the ones that tell you that cookies are used on a site) to tell them that there ip address is being stored?

Comment: You don't have to link the IP to a user in order to use it to limit new registrations. Just an IP with a timestamp in a list. Any IP entry more than 24 hrs old is deleted. Count how many times that IP has registered a new account in the past 24 hrs. Above the threshold, make them wait. Below it, let them register. Everyone stores your IP. If he isn't using several proxies then you could probably use your htaccess file to block his IP specifically so you don't tie up any server resources serving his bot pages.

Comment: @roggie The cookie warning is a legal requirement within the EU (and many web developers in the EU consider it rather heavy-handed). There is absolutely no requirement whatsoever to inform users that their IP address is being stored on the server. At least in the UK, an IP address alone is not personally identifiable information, especially since the user may be behind a proxy or one of many users on a wireless network, and most people have dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: It just occurred to me that since you know exactly who is doing this, maybe your best recourse is legal rather than technical? Threatening to set the law on him might be overkill, however.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I would do that but I want to be able to stop different people from doing this in the future.